# Sharepoint Online - Powershell Script to add permission to folders for eeach AAD group from CSV

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, script

This is my first post at stackexchange, so hello everyone.
I have issue. I created a script but its doesnt work.
I would like to add access to each folder at sharepoint for each group mapped from CSV
For example. AADGroup1 should has access to foldername: 76
AADGroup2 should has access to foldername: 173

I have CSV with 15000 groups, that should help me a lot. Thanks !

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

# Load the SharePoint PnP PowerShell module
Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline

# Connect to the SharePoint Online site
$SiteURL = "https://testnantname.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

# Read the data from the CSV file
$CSVFilePath = "C:\Skrypt\departments.csv"
$AccessData = Import-Csv $CSVFilePath

# Loop through each row of the CSV file
foreach ($row in $csvData)
{
    $folderName = $row.FolderName
    $groupName = $row.GroupName

    # Check if the folder exists in the "Documents" library
    $folder = Get-PnPFolder -Path "Shared Documents/$folderName" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($folder -ne $null)
    {
        # Add the group to the folder with contribute permissions
        $group = Get-PnPGroup -Name $groupName
        if ($group -ne $null)
        {
            Add-PnPFolderPermission -Identity $folder.ServerRelativeUrl -Group $group.Title -AddRole "Contribute"
            Write-Host "Permissions added for group $groupName on folder $folderName"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Group $groupName not found"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Folder $folderName not found in Shared Documents"
    }
}

# Disconnect from the SharePoint Online site
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

CSV file example build:

[image]

I'm receiving a error about module. But also scipt is not writed properly.

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:6 char:1
+ Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `-Name` parameter to the first line of your script:

```
Install-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
```

Additionally, you might benefit from using the newer `PnP.PowerShell` rather than the legacy `SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline`